# How to escape from a loop's team of task?

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I have two kind of jobs to do, `foobar1` to be done 3 times in parallel and `foobar2` to be done 5 times in parallel.
My Idea is to make the master thread create those two teams of work. but I face one difficulty.

Is It possible to make a thread escape from a parallel loop ? I mean to realize such a code where the master task can
escape the first team of work to create the second team

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    // first team of task which will execute the foobar1 function in parallel

    #pragma omp for schedule(static,1) nowait 
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp master
        {
            //escape here to create a second team in parallel
        }

        foobar1();
    }

    // second team of task which will execute the foobar2
    #pragma omp for schedule(static,1) nowait
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        foobar2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying split the 8 threads such that 3 run the first loop and 5 run the second loop?

Comment: @Mysticial, Yeah that exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one (clean) approach that completely bypasses your problem:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (i < 3){
        foobar1();
    }else{
        foobar2();
    }
}
```

If this isn't suitable, then the other solution I have in mind is to use nested parallelism. But that's messy.

Comment: @Mystical, thank for this answer, now imagine the case where `foobar2` contents nested loop. Is It possible that some of the 8 threads available here could work in nested loop of `foobar2` function ? thanks a lot for your time

Comment: You could probably let it some of the threads "fall-through" to the inner loop. But I'm not exactly sure what you mean without an example - probably better as a separate question.